# Model addAttribute() can't load to the corresponding JSP tag, when using Ajax to handle a form

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to process a form using Ajax post-method, everything in my controller works fine, except when I am trying to call model.addAttribute("jspTagName", string); it doesn't work, literally nothing happens.
This is the code of my Ajax handler

```
$("#filtring-form").submit(function(e){
var url = "/MessageCenterStatistics/results";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#filtring-form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        //TODO: 


    }});}
```

The following is my JSP page code in a jsp file called index.jsp, I am just showing you a simple case here of course

```
<form id="filtring-form">
<label>From date </label><input type="Date" name="fromDate" require/>
<label>Up to date </label><input type="Date" name="toDate" required/>
<button type="submit" id="dosomething">Get Statistics</button> 
<button type="reset">Reset </button> 
</form>
<div>
<p id="tag1">${something}</p>
</div>
```

I am just showing here simplified version of my Java Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processform(Model model, @RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate,
        @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate) {
    String s="Hello World!";
    model.addAttribute("something", s);

    return "index";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing `form` `submit` and it makes your page `reload`.

So in you following ajax you need to `prevent` the default behavior of page submit and reload so that you can see the updated modal having relevant attributes.

```
$("#filtring-form").submit(function(e){
 // prevent defaults
 e.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
       url: "/MessageCenterStatistics/results",
       data: $("#filtring-form").serialize(),
       success: function(data){
          //TODO: 
       }
 });

 return false;
}
```

Also you **should not** return anything from your handler method. Make it `void` instead of returning `string`. As you are returning string and the `index` is view jsp it renders the page newly once again recreating a new modal for you. So if you make it `void` and modify `modal` with `addAttribute()` then you will see it in jsp view.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void processform(Model model, @RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate,
        @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate) {
    String s="Hello World!";
    model.addAttribute("something", s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried to use your Ajax but still it doesn't work, let me add that, my application is intended to be in single web JSP page. in other words, the html code you see above is located in a file called index.jsp and it's the same file I want to display my jsp's tag (<p id="tag1">${something}</p>) value using model.addAttribute method.

Comment: @MahmudAlJabri  see my updated answer. You are returning a new view from controller method which might causing issue

Comment: Thank you, it sounds logical what you have said, but I am a beginner in Java, may I ask how would I modify my model?

Comment: I have tried it indeed, maybe there was something I didn't mention which was I used the following annotation as a top level annotation in my App Controller class : @Controller.